# Publish/subscribe on a single AllJoyn object

Tags: notifications, alljoyn

I want to use a publish/subscribe model in my AllJoyn application. I have several objects that implement the same interface, then they differ only in object path. With the *Notification Service* it seems to me you can select only the application and not the specific object, while using the *Observer* you can specify only the interface (which would include all objects). What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If each of your objects publishes an About message, an About listener will be able to get the path from the About message. Look at the about and aboutlistener in alljoyn_core/samples for an example.